# What's the minimal permissions I need to configure for a GKE node pool to pull from a private GCR repo in the same project?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to configure my GKE cluster to pull from a private GCR repo in the same project. I am not using OAuth scopes but have associated a [least privilege service account](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#use_least_privilege_sa) with the default node pool and provided it with the `roles/storage.objectViewer` permission.

However, I am still receiving the following when trying to access this image:

`Failed to pull image "eu.gcr.io/<project>/<image>": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication`

Do I also need to configure [`imagePullSecrets`](https://container-solutions.com/using-google-container-registry-with-kubernetes/) or should the `roles/storage.objectViewer` permission be sufficient?

Comment: Where exactly do you see this error?

Comment: When I describe the pod

Comment: Would you provide all the roles and permissions (if using custom roles) assigned to the service account. This gcloud command should help with roles $gcloud projects get-iam-policy ProjectID | grep -A 6 serviceAccount:xxxx@ProjectID.iam.gserviceaccount.com (replace 6 with the number of lines needed to show the role assigned)

Comment: @Fady thanks, see my answer for the root cause

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The root cause of this issue was not setting access (OAuth) scopes on the cluster instances preventing the service account from working as intended.

From the GCP docs about [Compute service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#usingroles) :

> **You must set access scopes on the instance to authorize access.**
>
> You cannot set only IAM roles on the service account and omit access scopes when creating the virtual machine instance. The level of access a service account has is determined by a combination of access scopes and IAM roles so you must configure both access scopes and IAM roles for the service account to work properly.

The minimal scopes required when accessing private images in GCR can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#reduce_node_sa_scopes) with the meaning of these scopes found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes). A least privilege service account for the cluster nodes can then be created following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#use_least_privilege_sa).

As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#service_account_permissions) an alternative would be to only grant the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope to the cluster nodes which authorises access to all Cloud Platform services and then limit access through IAM roles on node service accounts.

By configuring the cluster nodes as above, `imagePullSecrets` are not required for pulling private images from GCR in the same project.

Comment: Thanks to pointing the GCE docs about service accounts!
I've also followed the "Hardening your cluster's security" steps and blocked on same issue. This page is quite bit unclear about combination of access scopes and service accounts.

Comment: yeah was a bit of a pain finding the snippets of docs to understand everything fully

Comment: Im very confused I thought scopes were legacy and could be 100% replaced by service accounts. reading the docs confuse me more, what does this mean: `The best practice is to set the full cloud-platform access scope on the instance, then securely limit the service account's access using IAM roles.` does that mean the instances have like owner permissions to everything in the project? how is that a best practice?

Comment: I guess the final permissions of a node can be thought of as the intersection of scopes and service account iam roles, so by giving a node the `cloud-platform` scope (as you say, full scope access to everything) the final permissions is effectively just what is granted by the service account iam roles

Comment: God I hate GCP, this is soo confusing! Thanks for sharing the critical detail.