# gcloud cluster cannot pull eu.gcr.io authentication required

Tags: docker, authentication, kubernetes, gcloud, kubernetes-helm

I have set up a Kubernetes cluster on gcloud via gitlab.

I have some trouble pulling my images when I deploy my application.

I use a gcloud cluster with a registry on the same gcloud project. Normally, I'm able to pull my image directly without any modification (supposed to use the **Compute Engine default service account?**).

But I get a unauthorized on my pod when he try to pull the image :

```
  Warning  Failed                 3m (x2 over 3m)  kubelet, gke-production-default-pool-********-****  Failed to pull image "eu.gcr.io/[My-Project]/services-identity:715bfffa": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unauthorized: authentication required
  Warning  Failed                 3m (x2 over 3m)  kubelet, gke-production-default-pool-********-****  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff                2m (x6 over 3m)  kubelet, gke-production-default-pool-********-****  Back-off pulling image "eu.gcr.io/[My-Project]/services-identity:715bfffa"
  Warning  Failed                 2m (x6 over 3m)  kubelet, gke-production-default-pool-********-****  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling                2m (x3 over 3m)  kubelet, gke-production-default-pool-********-****  pulling image "eu.gcr.io/[My-Project]/services-identity:715bfffa"
```

I deploy via gitlab-ci with the following command line:

```
helm upgrade --install services-identity -f ./deploy/env/production-values.yml ./deploy/ --set image.tag=${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8} --namespace=production --wait
```

For information, I can pull the registry when this one is public, I can also pull the image locally via a docker login(using my gcloud account).

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to this: [What's the minimal permissions I need to configure for a GKE node pool to pull from a private GCR repo in the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53008125/whats-the-minimal-permissions-i-need-to-configure-for-a-gke-node-pool-to-pull-f/53018981#53018981), except that you are not mentioning that it's on GKE so I assume is on GCE.

You can use a [`json_key_file`](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json_key_file).

On all your nodes (assuming you are using Docker):

```
$ docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io
```

Or the same json_key_file using [`ImagePullSecrets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) in the pod spec as described [here](https://container-solutions.com/using-google-container-registry-with-kubernetes/).

Or you can use on all your Kubernetes nodes:

```
$ gcloud auth configure-docker
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your helpful response. On the similar issues you have shared, I have found a solution [Use Least Privilege Service Accounts for your Nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#use_least_privilege_sa).

The problem is on the **Cloud API access scopes** level, I have recreated an InstanceGroup with the right scope:

> The default scopes for the nodes in GKE are devstorage.read_only,
>   logging.write, monitoring, service.management.readonly,
>   servicecontrol, and trace.append. When setting scopes, these are
>   specified as gke-default. If you are accessing private images in
>   Google Container Registry, the minimally required scopes are only
>   logging.write, monitoring, and devstorage.read_only.